# Parameter in constructor: Structs vs classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Why does the following code snippet not work?

```
public struct AStruct
{
    public bool Fi { get; set; }

    public string Fei{ get; set; }

    public bool Fo{ get; set; }

    public string Fam{ get; set; }

    public AStruct(bool fi, string fei, bool fo, string fam)
        : this()
    {
        this.Fi = fi;
        this.Fei = fei;
        this.Fo = fo;
        this.Fam = fam;
    }
}
```

and at last call it in a constructor of a control

```
public GS(AStruct astruct)
    {}
```

Visual Studio 2012 and the compiler complain, that AStruct is not found.

If I change it to

```
public class AStruct
{
....
}
public AStruct(bool fi, string fei, bool fo, string fam)
{
.... 
}
```

it does not complain any longer...

Any clues?

Comment: Are you sure AStruct is in the correct namespace?

Comment: The culprit is `:this()`. Structs are different in that way.

Comment: @peer I just cleened it up a bit for SO so that not too much code is shown ...

Comment: @Candidate the `:this()` is needed for structs if you have auto-generated properties - in other classes it also works fine. Only in the Control class it isn't found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `AStruct` doesn't have a parameters less constructor the compiler complains. So why bother adding the `: this()` to the parametered constructor?

And then again, structs can't contain a parameter less constructor [[MSDN]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2xcf8ft%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

I have read a bit into it, I now guess that you have a namespace problem. If the namespace is correct I suggest you try to restart Visual Studio and do a rebuild. I sometimes have an unexplained error and after a Visual Studio restart and a rebuild the problem is solved.

Else, could we get the error code? CS....

Comment: Without `:this()` the compiler will complain about the struct. It is needed if you have AutoProperties. It is also not complaining about the struct, it is only complaining at the constructor of the Control that it cannot find the STruct. In other classes the struct is already used...

Comment: try in the constructor to use the full name of the struct. `public GS(My.Name.Space.Foo.Bar.Astruct astruct) { }`

Comment: Oh, i changed the struct to a class in the same file / namespace, so it shouldn't be a namespace problem. Funilly restart of the studio (clean, build) did it.